# Using PSQL COPY in postgres

Tags: postgresql, copy, plpgsql, psql

I need to include \copy for my postgres code .

```
do language plpgsql $$
declare
begin
  \copy from tab1'C:\\Documents\test.csv' DELIMITER E'\t' CSV HEADER ;
  insert into tab2 select * from tab1 ;
when others then 
  raise exception 
end; $$;
```

I need to capture exception for my `\copy` so I use postgres but I am not able to use `\copy`. `copy` command ask for super user which is not possible so how can I use `\copy` in PL/pgSQL code.

Is there any work around?

Comment: `\copy` is a `psql` specific command. It can't be used in SQL or PL/pgSQL. But I don't see why you would need PL/pgSQL at all here. You could run those two commands directly without the use of a DO block.

Comment: Thanks . I initially did that only but i need to capture exception for my whole block which led me to go for PL/pgsql

Comment: You can capture exceptions on the client side just as well.

Comment: thanks for your comment . how to do it? should i use a function which returns trigger if copy failed?

Comment: 1) A function that returns `trigger` only works when called by a `CREATE TRIGGER ...` statement that attaches said trigger to a table. It will not work as stand alone function. 2) As to client capturing exceptions it depends on the client. For example a Python client would use `try: <some query> except as e <some_exception_type>: <handle_exception>`.